# Many-to-many hibernate mapping if link table is having extra columns mappings

Tags: java, beginner, hibernate

I have many-to-many mapping with extra columns in the join table.  The table structure looks like this:

```
table vendor{vendor_id, vendor_name, vendor_password, etc...}
table student{student_id, student_name, student_password, etc..}
table test{test_id, test_subject, test_price,test_level, etc..}
```

Relations as follows:

```
vendor to test --> many-to-many
student to test --> many-to-many
```

The link:

```
table vendor_student_test{vendor_id, student_id, test_id, purchasedDate, assignedDate, writtenDate, result}
```

I've created POJO classes as follows:

**Vendor.java**

```
public class Vendor {
    private Long vendorId;
    private String vendorName;
    private String vendorPassword;
    private Set<VendorStudentTest> tests;
    private boolean isVendorActivate;
    public boolean isVendorActivate() {
        return isVendorActivate;
    }
    public void setVendorActivate(boolean isVendorActivate) {
        this.isVendorActivate = isVendorActivate;
    }
    public Set<VendorStudentTest> getTests() {
        return tests;
    }
    public void setTests(Set<VendorStudentTest> tests) {
        this.tests = tests;
    }
    public Long getVendorId() {
        return vendorId;
    }
    public void setVendorId(Long vendorId) {
        this.vendorId = vendorId;
    }
    public String getVendorName() {
        return vendorName;
    }
    public void setVendorName(String vendorName) {
        this.vendorName = vendorName;
    }
    public String getVendorPassword() {
        return vendorPassword;
    }
    public void setVendorPassword(String vendorPassword) {
        this.vendorPassword = vendorPassword;
    }

}
```

**Student.java**

```
public class Student {
    private Long studentId;
    private String studentName;
    private String studentPassword;
    private Set<VendorStudentTest> tests;
    public Set<VendorStudentTest> getTests() {
        return tests;
    }
    public void setTests(Set<VendorStudentTest> tests) {
        this.tests = tests;
    }
    public Long getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }
    public void setStudentId(Long studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }
    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }
    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
    }
    public String getStudentPassword() {
        return studentPassword;
    }
    public void setStudentPassword(String studentPassword) {
        this.studentPassword = studentPassword;
    }

}
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test{
        private Long testId;
    private String testSubject;
    private int testTotalNoOfQuestions;
    private double testPrice;
    public Long getTestId() {
        return testId;
    }
    public void setTestId(Long testId) {
        this.testId = testId;
    }
    public String getTestSubject() {
        return testSubject;
    }
    public void setTestSubject(String testSubject) {
        this.testSubject = testSubject;
    }
    public int getTestTotalNoOfQuestions() {
        return testTotalNoOfQuestions;
    }
    public void setTestTotalNoOfQuestions(int testTotalNoOfQuestions) {
        this.testTotalNoOfQuestions = testTotalNoOfQuestions;
    }
    public double getTestPrice() {
        return testPrice;
    }
    public void setTestPrice(double testPrice) {
        this.testPrice = testPrice;
    }
    public int getTestLevel() {
        return testLevel;
    }
    public void setTestLevel(int testLevel) {
        this.testLevel = testLevel;
    }
    public Set<Question> getTestQuestions() {
        return testQuestions;
    }
    public void setTestQuestions(Set<Question> testQuestions) {
        this.testQuestions = testQuestions;
    }
    private int testLevel;
    private Set<Question> testQuestions;

}
```

**VendorStudentTest.java**

```
public class VendorStudentTest {
    private VendorStudentTestPK vendorStudentTestPK;
    private Date assignedDate;
    private Date purchasedDate;
    private Date writtenDate;
    private double result;
    public VendorStudentTestPK getVendorStudentTestPK() {
        return vendorStudentTestPK;
    }
    public void setVendorStudentTestPK(VendorStudentTestPK vendorStudentTestPK) {
        this.vendorStudentTestPK = vendorStudentTestPK;
    }
    public Date getAssignedDate() {
        return assignedDate;
    }
    public void setAssignedDate(Date assignedDate) {
        this.assignedDate = assignedDate;
    }
    public Date getPurchasedDate() {
        return purchasedDate;
    }
    public void setPurchasedDate(Date purchasedDate) {
        this.purchasedDate = purchasedDate;
    }
    public Date getWrittenDate() {
        return writtenDate;
    }
    public void setWrittenDate(Date writtenDate) {
        this.writtenDate = writtenDate;
    }
    public double getResult() {
        return result;
    }
    public void setResult(double result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

}
```

**VendorStudentTestPK.java**

```
public class VendorStudentTestPK {
    private Vendor vendor;
    private Student student;
    private Test test;

    public VendorStudentTestPK() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public VendorStudentTestPK(Vendor vendor, Student student, Test test) {
        super();
        this.vendor = vendor;
        this.student = student;
        this.test = test;
    }
    public Vendor getVendor() {
        return vendor;
    }
    public void setVendor(Vendor vendor) {
        this.vendor = vendor;
    }
    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }
    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }
    public Test getTest() {
        return test;
    }
    public void setTest(Test test) {
        this.test = test;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((student == null) ? 0 : student.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((test == null) ? 0 : test.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((vendor == null) ? 0 : vendor.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof VendorStudentTestPK))
            return false;
        VendorStudentTestPK other = (VendorStudentTestPK) obj;
        if (student == null) {
            if (other.student != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!student.equals(other.student))
            return false;
        if (test == null) {
            if (other.test != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!test.equals(other.test))
            return false;
        if (vendor == null) {
            if (other.vendor != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!vendor.equals(other.vendor))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Hibernate mapping files as follows:

**vendor.hbm.xml**

```
<class name="Vendor" table="vendor">
    <id name="vendorId" type="long" column="vendor_id">
        <generator class="increment"/>      
    </id>
    <property name="vendorName" column="vendor_name" type="string"/>
    <property name="vendorPassword" column="vendor_password" type="string"/>
    <set name="tests" table="vendor_student_test"
                inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="vendor_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="VendorStudentTest" />
        </set>

  </class>
```

**vendor_student_test.hbm.xml**

```
<class name="Vendor" table="vendor">
    <composite-id name="vendorStudentTestPK"
        class="com.onlineexam.model.VendorStudentTestPK">
        <key-property name="vendorId" column="vendor_id"
            type="java.lang.Long" />
        <key-property name="studentId" column="student_id"
            type="java.lang.Long" />
        <key-property name="testId" column="test_id" type="java.lang.Long" />
    </composite-id>

    <many-to-one name="vendor" class="Vendor" insert="false" update="false"/>
    <many-to-one name="student" class="Student" insert="false" update="false"/>
    <many-to-one name="test" class="Test" insert="false" update="false"/>

  </class>
```

**student.hbm.xml**

```
<class name="Student" table="student">
    <id name="studenId" type="long" column="student_id">
        <generator class="increment"/>      
    </id>
    <property name="studentName" column="student_name" type="string"/>
    <property name="studentPassword" column="student_password" type="string"/>
    <set name="tests" table="vendor_student_test"
                inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="student_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="VendorStudentTest" />
        </set>

  </class>
```

**test.hbm.xml**

```
//this is mapped to other table
```

I am new to hibernate.  Is this correct mapping?

Comment: I think you will find the solution in this link http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

Comment: thaks alot Anil Kumar, but have to do with hbm mappings, can u tell me above mapping is correct or not?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not familiar with Hibernate mappings, so just some other notes about the code:

1. Calling a class `Test` could be a disadvantage later. Build frameworks/tools could recognize your class erroneously as a JUnit test class. Although this might be the proper term in your domain I would still consider using a synonym.
2. It's confusing that some fields are at the end of the class, like these:

   ```
   private int testLevel;
   private Set<Question> testQuestions;
   ```

   ([Java Coding Conventions, 3.1.3 Class and Interface Declarations](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-141855.html#1852))
3. Instead of

   ```
   boolean isVendorActivate;
   ```

   I'd consider an enum. Enums are easier to read (you don't have to remember what true or false means) and later you might have other states which only need a new enum value (it's easier to extend).
4. ```
   double result;
   ```

   Are you sure that you want to use floating point values here? Floating point numbers are not precise, consider using a `BigDecimal`.

   - [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/843804)
   - *Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 48: Avoid float and double if exact answers are required*
5. About the comment:

   ```
   public VendorStudentTestPK() {
       super();
       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }
   ```

   If you have something to do then do it, otherwise remove the comment. It's just noise. (*Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*: *Chapter 4: Comments, Noise Comments*)
6. `VendorStudentTestPK` implements `hashCode` and `equals` and they call `Student`'s, `Test`'s and `Vendor`'s `hashCode`/`equals` but none of these classes implements `hashCode` nor `equals`. Are you sure that they shouldn't have `hashCode` and `equals`?